# Marshelling error for travelport AirPriceReq API

Tags: soap, postman, http-post, travelport-api

I am trying to get pricing details of a certain flight number using pre-production credentials for target branch P7193093 by using uAPI AirPriceReq. The response is'A general marshalling exception occurred.' including a TransactionId '71603C220A0D6A956050B65EB21624C5'.
I am not sure if this is related to target branch or authentication error.
Any insight would be appreciated.

Shared below is the URL and its request response
URL - https://americas.universal-api.pp.travelport.com/B2BGateway/connect/uAPI/AirService

Req:-

```
<s:Envelope
xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<AirPriceReq
xmlns="http://www.travelport.com/schema/air_v18_0"
TargetBranch="P7193093"
AuthorizedBy=""
TraceId="b2ad1866-b41a-4885-a557-79e03c2806a9"
FareRuleType="long">
<BillingPointOfSaleInfo
xmlns="http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v15_0"
OriginApplication="uAPI"/>
<AirItinerary>
<AirSegment
Key="C/OEKtTqWDKAHspWIAAAAA=="
Status="NN"
Equipment="73G"
AvailabilitySource="Seamless"
Origin="SYD"
Destination="MEL"
DepartureTime="2023-11-01T06:30:00.000+11:00"
FlightNumber="405"
Group="0" 
Carrier="QF" 
ArrivalTime="2023-11-01T08:05:00.000+11:00"
ProviderCode="1V"
FlightTime="95"
TravelTime="P1DT1H45M0S">
<CodeshareInfo
OperatingCarrier="CO">Continental</CodeshareInfo>
</AirSegment>
</AirItinerary>
<AirPricingModifiers
FaresIndicator="PublicAndPrivateFares">
<ExemptTaxes/>
</AirPricingModifiers>
<SearchPassenger
xmlns="http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v15_0"
PricePTCOnly="false"
Code="ADT"/>
<AirPricingCommand/>
</AirPriceReq>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Response

```
<SOAP:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP:Body>
<SOAP:Fault>
<faultcode>Server.System</faultcode>
<faultstring>A general marshalling exception occurred.</faultstring>
<detail>
<common_v51_0:ErrorInfo
xmlns:common_v51_0="http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v51_0">
<common_v51_0:Code>1201</common_v51_0:Code>
<common_v51_0:Service>WEBSVC</common_v51_0:Service>
<common_v51_0:Type>System</common_v51_0:Type>
<common_v51_0:Description>A general marshalling exception occurred.</common_v51_0:Description>
<common_v51_0:TransactionId>71603C220A0D6A956050B65EB21624C5</common_v51_0:TransactionId>
</common_v51_0:ErrorInfo>
</detail>
</SOAP:Fault>
</SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```